# Why does Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor#createQueue specify BlockingQueue<Runnable> as return type when it accepts submitting Callable<T>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, priority-queue, threadpoolexecutor

I was trying to override Spring [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) [protected createQueue(int queueCapacity)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#createQueue-int-) method to customize it by creating and returning a [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) instead of the default (`LinkedBlockingQueue`/`SynchronousQueue`).
In doing so the question that arose for me is if the method requires creating & returning a [BlockingQueue<Runnable>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html?is-external=true) how does it work when the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` itself accepts submitting [Callables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) if the underlying `BlockingQueue` can only hold `Runnable`?

Thanks

Comment: That's like asking "Why can an `ArrayList` have a dynamic size, when arrays, which `ArrayList` is based on, has a fixed size?" Short answer: It's part of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no problem here. A `Callable` represents a bunch of code that can be run, that returns a value and potentially throws an exception. If we ignore the return value, and handle the exception somehow, then it can be used as a `Runnable`!

For example:

```
class CallableRunnable implements Runnable {
  private final Callable<?> callable;
  
  public CallableRunnable(Callable<?> callable) {
    this.callable = callable;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      callable.call();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      // some exception handling...
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can convert any `Callable` into a `Runnable` like this:

```
new CallableRunnable(someCallable)
```

Of course, how this is actually done in `ThreadPoolExecutor` (which is what `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is based on) is a lot more complicated. `submit` needs to return a `Future`, so it would also need to wrap the `Callable` into a `Future`, as well as a `Runnable`.

`AbstractExecutorService` (which `ThreadPoolExecutor` inherits from) wraps the `Callable`s passed into `submit` into [`FutureTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)s, and you can have a look at what their `run` method looks like [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk12u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#L254) if you are interested. It's essentially the same structure as what I wrote above, just with more `Future`-related logic and managing the state of the `Future`.